# Spork rspec while using redis, raise Redis::InheritedError

Tags: rspec, redis, spork

If the code excute redis related function, it will raise

> Redis::InheritedError: Tried to use a connection from a child process without reconnecting. You need to reconnect to Redis after forking.

when redis connect it will save the spork process.pid as @pid, then redis excute it will check the connect using `ensure_connected`, which will check by `Process.pid != @pid`. and these two pids are different, so it raise Redis::InheritedError.

By Google it,

```
Resque.after_fork do 
  Resque.redis.client.reconnect
end
```

and reconnect the redis client every spec

Both of them don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrade redis to 2.6.12, the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here, and it worked for me: [Hacki.ly](http://www.hacki.ly/post/39595212553/rspec-spork-and-redis)

Looks like it's a matter of adding the following in your spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config| 
  # ... 
  config.before :all do
    $redis.client.reconnect 
  end 
  # ... 
end
```

You may need to change `$redis` to whatever you're using to grab a reference to your Redis instance.

Comment: You still get the `Redis::InheritedError`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding the following to spec_helper.rb:

```
Spork.each_run do
  $redis.client.reconnect
end
```

Also as mentioned in Gabe's answer, you may need to change `$redis` to whatever you're using to grab a reference to your Redis instance.